# Ruby on Rails: Token Fields - railscast

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I am trying to get token fields to work on my app.

I have followed this video exactly: http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields

**project model**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible  :edited_first_name, :edited_last_name, :first_name, :last_name, :business_div, :client, :customer_benifits, :edited_date, :end_date, :entry_date,  :financials, :industry, :keywords, :lessons_learned, :project_name, :project_owner, :role, :start_date, :status, :summary, :tech , :technols, :technol_tokens


has_many :projecttechnols
has_many :technols, :through => :projecttechnols

attr_reader :technol_tokens

  def technol_tokens=(ids)
    self.technol_ids = ids.split(",")
  end


accepts_nested_attributes_for(:technols)
```

**technols controller:**

```
def index
    @technols = Technol.where("tech like ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render :json => @technols.map(&:attributes) }
    end
  end
```

**layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<div id="user_nav">
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    Hi <%= current_user.firstname %>, Signed in as  <%= current_user.email %>.  Not you?

<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path %> or
    <%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<% if current_user.try(:admin?) %>
 <div class="admin_button">
<%= button_to "ADMIN", users_path, :class => "button", :method => "get" %>

</div>




<% end %>
  <title>ExceptionApp</title>



<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", "token-input-facebook" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<link href="application.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">


<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON"
       href="/assets/minilogo.png">



<%= link_to(image_tag("/assets/logo.png"), projects_path, :class => "logow") %>

</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>


<style>
.debug {


position:absolute; right:0px; bottom:0px;

}
</style>
<div class ="debug">
<%= debug(params) %>
<div>


<%= content_tag(:div, flash[:error], :id => "flash_error") if flash[:error] %>
<%= content_tag(:div, flash[:alert], :id => "flash_alert") if flash[:alert] %>
<!-- Javascripts
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults, "application", "jquery.tokeninput" %>

  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

**project/new.html.erb**

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "new" %>


<h1>Create New Project</h1>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag "form" %>


<%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>



<p>
    <%= f.label :technol_tokens, "technol" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :technol_tokens, "data-pre" => @project.technols.map(&:attributes).to_json %>
  </p>



</BODY>
</HTML>


<div class="create_button">
<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Save New Project", :class => "button",  :confirm => "Are you sure you want to save the new project?" %>
  </div>
</div>




</div> <%#= small div %>





<% end %>



<div class="back_button2">
<%= button_to "Back", projects_path , :class => "button", :method => "get" %>
</div>
```

**application.js** EDIT:

```
$(function() {
  $("#project_technol_tokens").tokenInput("/technols.json", {
    crossDomain: false,
    prePopulate: $("#project_technol_tokens").data("pre"),
    theme: "facebook"
  });
});



$(function() {
  $("#project_start_date").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
});

$(function() {
  $("#project_end_date").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
});



jQuery(function(){

jQuery('#start_date_A').datepicker({dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"});
});

jQuery(function(){

jQuery('#start_date_B').datepicker({dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"});
});
```

On my new page already, I have a jquery datepicker text box that works. I don't understand why the token field on the same page doesn't work.

I have followed the video exactly about 3 times to make sure, and it still doesn't work. Only differences are that I put my javascripts and stylesheets in the assets folder, where in the video it goes in the public folder. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tested your JSON data? Also you need to have the JS inside a  document ready so it´s executed on page load..

Comment: I navigated to localhost:3000/technols.json and the data was displayed, and on that new page, I have already managed to get javascript working on it

Comment: The javascript for the token field doesn't load. I have posted an edited version off my application.js

Comment: There is an updated railscast using JQuery TokenInput which starts around 4:00 min into the railscast. http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields-revised

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a likely error. Please try the following:

1. Check your application.js file. Have you included the jquery.tokeninput.js file?
2. Make sure that the token-input js file is required after jquery in application.js
3. Check to make sure the CSS files are included
4. In the browser, are you getting any js errors in the console? If so please ammend question.

**Edit**

Also, I just noticed, in your new.html.erb you have a div after the html closing tag!

```
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Please remove / place these in the proper place.